# ImageMagick has issues with some PDFs

Tags: php, imagemagick, ghostscript

I'm having problems with some PDFs when I convert them to 'jpg'; it only happen with some of them when I execute the code with `exec()`. I'm using PHP, but when I execute the same code directly in the server it works great.

This is the error that throws me:

> [0] => Error: /invalidaccess in --.execform1--
>
> [1] => Operand stack:
>
> [2] =>    --dict:8/17(L)--   1   10   4   15   6   18   C2_2   10   --dict:6/6(L)--   --dict:6/6(L)--   FrutigerLTStd-Roman   --dict:11/12(ro)(G)--   --nostringval--   CIDFontObject   --dict:7/7(L)--   --dict:7/7(L)--   725745   --dict:7/7(L)--   --nostringval--   PDFCIDFontName   FrutigerLTStd-Roman
>
> [3] => Execution stack:
>
> [4] =>    %interp_exit   .runexec2   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   2   %stopped_push   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   false   1   %stopped_push   1846   1   3   %oparray_pop   1845   1   3   %oparray_pop   1829   1   3   %oparray_pop   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   2   1   1   --nostringval--   %for_pos_int_continue   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   %array_continue   --nostringval--   false   1   %stopped_push   --nostringval--   %loop_continue   --nostringval--   9656   --nostringval--   1794   4   11   %oparray_pop   --nostringval--   false   1   %stopped_push   1793   4   11   %oparray_pop   --nostringval--   (gstatetype)   --dict:0/0(L)--   --nostringval--   false   1   %stopped_push   --nostringval--   %loop_continue   --nostringval--   726421   --nostringval--   1794   6   16   %oparray_pop   --nostringval--   false   1   %stopped_push   1793   6   16   %oparray_pop   --nostringval--   (gstatetype)   --dict:4/4(L)--   --nostringval--   false   1   %stopped_push   --nostringval--   %loop_continue   --nostringval--   725947   --nostringval--   1794   8   19   %oparray_pop   --nostringval--   false   1   %stopped_push   1793   8   19   %oparray_pop   --nostringval--   (gstatetype)   --dict:1/1(L)--   --nostringval--   false   1   %stopped_push   --nostringval--   %loop_continue   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   %array_continue   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--
>
> [5] => Dictionary stack:
>
> [6] =>    --dict:1154/1684(ro)(G)--   --dict:1/20(G)--   --dict:75/200(L)--   --dict:75/200(L)--   --dict:106/127(ro)(G)--   --dict:286/300(ro)(G)--   --dict:22/25(L)--   --dict:4/6(L)--   --dict:22/40(L)--   --dict:1/1(ro)(G)--   --dict:2/5(L)--   --dict:1/1(ro)(G)--   --dict:1/1(ro)(G)--   --dict:1/1(ro)(G)--   --dict:1/1(ro)(G)--   --dict:2/5(L)--   --dict:1/1(ro)(G)--   --dict:1/1(ro)(G)--   --dict:2/5(L)--   --dict:1/1(ro)(G)--   --dict:9/15(L)--   --dict:1/1(ro)(G)--   --dict:1/1(ro)(G)--
>
> [7] => Current allocation mode is local

Does anyone have deal with this problem too?

Answer (score 0):

The errors are from Ghostscript, what version of GS do you have installed ?

Note that invalidaccess may be due to file permissions, from your stack trace its trying to execute a CIDFont so it may be that there is a permissions problem with the font directory. Its only a theory but the fact that it only fails when you are running under PHP supports it. You probably need to look at the environment and permissions of the PHP 'user'

Comment: Im using the last version of GS. 
Weird thing is that when I open the pdf and save it with different name, it works... maybe it is about permissions.

Comment: More specifically please. Last version could mean anything depending on which OS you are using. Have you checked the environment, groups and permissions of the users ?

Comment: I'd have to say it sounds like a permissions problem, at a guess it can't open a font file, judging by the error message